Arima function in R incorrectly including an additional MA term
When fitting an ARIMA model (with Arima function from the forecast package) there is an additional hidden MA term.
library(astsa)
library(forecast)
set.seed(99)
simul_sarima <- 5 + sarima.sim(ar=0.0, d=0, ma=-.3, sar=0.8, D=0, sma=-.2, S=12, n=1200)
fit_sarima <- Arima(simul_sarima, order=c(0,0,1), seasonal=c(1,0,1))
summary(fit_sarima)
print(fit_sarima$model$phi)
print(fit_sarima$model$theta)

ARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,1)[12] with non-zero mean 

          ma1    sar1    sma1    mean
      -0.2904  0.7911  -0.234  4.9963

Phi:
0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.7911284

Theta:
-0.29039562  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000 -0.23395825  0.06794045

Phi is OK:
AR12 = 0.7911284
Theta has:
MA1 = -0.29039562;
MA12 = -0.23395825;
MA13 = 0.06794045
Why the MA13 term?
I've manually calculated predictions. They are considering this last MA13 term.

SARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,1)[12] is a restricted ARIMA(12,0,13) with nonzero coefficients at exactly the same lags that you are getting. If you write down the equation explicitly, you will see.

The ARIMA(0,0,1)(1,0,1)[12] model has two MA terms. In backshift notation, these terms can be written as $$(1+\theta B)(1+\Theta B^{12}) = 1 + \theta B + \Theta B^{12} + \theta\Theta B^{13}.$$ So the resulting polynomial operator has 3 coefficients at lags 1, 12 and 13. This is what the fit_sarima$model$theta term is returning.
